# Why obtain AppCompat resource through TintTypedArray doesn't work

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I try to mimic the code in AppCompat v7

[AppCompat v7 source code](https://github.com/yccheok/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java#L280)

```
final TintTypedArray a = TintTypedArray.obtainStyledAttributes(context, attrs, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.SearchView, defStyleAttr, 0);
Drawable drawable = a.getDrawable(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.SearchView_closeIcon);
```

I expect the above code can help me to get the following drawable

[abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha.png](https://github.com/yccheok/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha.png)

However, it turns out to be `null`.

If I wrote it in the way

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha)
```

It would work. I was wondering, why the `TintTypedArray`'s version doesn't work for me? My application theme is

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Does that matter? How can I make `TintTypedArray`'s version return me a drawable?

Answer (score 1):

`TypedArray` cannot be used like this.

#### The solution

```
final Drawable d = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha);
```

This drawable is not present in recent versions of AppCompat library. It's been replaced with vector XML drawable. This method will resolve compat vector drawables.

Here's the legacy code using internal AppCompat API:

```
final Drawable d = AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(context, R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha);
```

#### How to use TypedArray or TintTypedArray

These classes are intended for resolving *theme attributes* or *widget style attributes* to resources. Not *resource IDs* to resources.

```
<declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
    <attr name="someNumber" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="someImage" format="drawable"/>
</declare-styleable>

final TintTypedArray ta = TintTypedArray.obtainStyledAttributes(context, attrs, R.styleable.MyCustomView, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
final int someNumber = ta.getInt(R.styleable.MyCustomView_someNumber, -1);
final Drawable someImage = ta.getInt(R.styleable.MyCustomView_someImage);
ta.recycle();
```

Instead of `R.styleable.*` you can use a custom **SORTED** Java array of `android.R.attr.*` and `R.attr.*` values. Access values with a zero-based index.